# stdbool.hが読み込めない

Tags: visual-studio

visual studio2015で作成したプロジェクトをvisual studio2012の方でビルドを実行したところ，

> プロジェクトファイルに ToolsVersion="14.0" が含まれています。 
>   このツールセットが不明であるか、存在しない可能性があります。その場合は、適切なバージョンの MSBuild をインストールして解決するか、ビルドがポリシー上の理由により特定の ToolsVersion を使用するよう強制されている可能性があります。プロジェクトをToolsversion="4.0"として扱っています。

と表示され，`#include<stdbool.h>`に赤い波線が付きました。
visual studio2015のバージョンをインストールする以外に解決方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: Visual Studio 2015とVisual Studio 2012の両方を併用される理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: 実験装置に用いているPCが新しいのに変更されたのですが，その新しいPCに教授が2012をインストールしたためです．